# Is there a way to insert permissions using google drive api to a folder containing subfolders?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google has recently changed the permission propagation for drive.file scope. If you try to give permission to a folder containing subfolder(s) the following error occurs:

```
Google.Apis.Requests. RequestError: The authenticated user may not have granted the app xxx write access to all of the children of file yyy [403]
```

I tried to firstly insert permissions to all subfolders and then to the parent folder. Inserting permissions to subfolders succeeds but inserting permissions to the parent folder gives again the same error. I can confirm this is not an issue in the general drive scope. Any solution?

Comment: I've seen that exception when deleting. It seems to be triggered by having more than 100 children for any action that propagates downwards.

Comment: @pinoyyid I am having only one child folder.

Comment: how many files in total under the folder and all of its subfolders?

Comment: @pinoyyid The folders are empty of files

Comment: @pinoyyid I tested the issue with the general drive scope and there was not any error.